# How to discover the IP addresses within a network with a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Is it possible to determine the IP addresses of systems within a network using a bash script? And how?

Comment: Do you want to run a script to discover the active IP addresses in a network? Or to discover the IP of the current system?

Comment: I want to run the script to determine the active IP address of all the systems.

Comment: Why bash? Is this for convenience, or is there a more specific requirement?

Comment: Similar question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548032/find-internal-ip-address-with-bash

Comment: I need to incorparate that feature with another script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install arp-scan (`sudo apt-get install arp-scan`) and add the following line to the script:

```
IPs=$(sudo arp-scan --localnet --numeric --quiet --ignoredups | grep -E '([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Now you have all the active IP addresses in the `IPs` variable.

Note: this will only work on a directly connected network, i.e. not accessed through a router.

PS: If you install `gawk` the command can be shortened to (thanks [belacqua](https://askubuntu.com/u/8844)):

```
IPs=$(sudo arp-scan --localnet --quiet --ignoredups | gawk '/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/ {print $1}')
```

Comment: You don't need grep at all, just `| awk  '/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/ {print $1}') ` .  However, I think the straight arp-scan output is nicer.

Comment: @belacqua Thanks, but I used `grep` because I couldn't get it working using only `awk`. If I use those curly braces to indicate a repetition awk outputs nothing. Do you know how to make that regex work in awk?

Comment: Hmm -- this worked for me: `sudo arp-scan --localnet --quiet --ignoredups | awk  '/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/ {print $1}'` .  and `IPs=$(sudo arp-scan --localnet --quiet --ignoredups | awk  '/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/ {print $1}')`

Comment: @belacqua No, doesn't work for me. Tested on 12.04 and 13.04 with same results, no output. Even weirder, if I use `'/[a-f0-9]:[a-f0-9]/ {print $1}'` it works, but with `'/[a-f0-9]:[a-f0-9]:[a-f0-9]/ {print $1}'` it doesn't.

Comment: @belacqua The correct regex in my last comment should be `'/[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]:[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]/ {print $1}'`, and it indeed works. But `'/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/ {print $1}'` still isn't working.

Comment: What happens if you use `awk --posix`?  Kind of makes this more trouble than it's worth....   But that flag is supposed to make egrep and awk consistent for regexps.  Also, what does `awk --version` give you?  Looks like alternatives supplies me with gawk 4.0.1 .

Comment: @belacqua Success! `--posix` and `--version` result in `not an option:`. Alternatives was linking awk to mawk (version 1.3.3). I installed gawk and now it works. Thanks very much, I learned alot from all of this.

Comment: @EricCarvalho  Cool.  Also a good learning experience for me.

Comment: `arp-scan` also supports `--interface` to select a particular network interface to scan.

Answer (score 7):

This answer uses the `nmap` command to gather information of active hosts in the network.

> Nmap ("Network Mapper") is an open source tool for network exploration
>   and security auditing. It was designed to rapidly scan large networks,
>   although it works fine against single hosts. Nmap uses raw IP packets
>   in novel ways to determine what hosts are available on the network,
>   what services (application name and version) those hosts are offering,
>   what operating systems (and OS versions) they are running, what type
>   of packet filters/firewalls are in use, and dozens of other
>   characteristics.

Assuming you need to scan the 192.168.0.X range, you can try:

```
nmap -v -sP 192.168.0.0/24
```

Where `192.168.0.0` is the network address and `/24` is the network mask equivalent to `255.255.255.0`. Thus the above command will scan 256 hosts.

To collect the active IP addresses, one can use the following line:

```
IPS_UP=$(nmap -nsP 192.168.0.0/24 2>/dev/null -oG - | grep "Up$" | awk '{printf "%s ", $2}')
```

It actually concatenates the list of active IP addresses (filtered by `grep`) into a variable called `IPS_UP`:

- `nmap` is run with switches `-n` (no name resolution), `-sP` (ping scan) and `-oG` to output a grep processable output onto the standard output (`-`).
- `grep` filters only lines containing the word "Up" at the end of line ("$").
- `awk` prints the second column in the list output by `nmap`, which is the IP address, and appends a space.
- The `$()` command substitution allows the output of the chain of commands to be assigned to the `IPS_UP` variable.

The Network Mapper can be installed by using `sudo apt-get install nmap`.

**Note**
`nmap` might discover more hosts if run by a privileged user. This is because different kind of packets are sent to scan a host. By modifying the above line to read `sudo nmap ...` allows to run the `nmap` command as root.

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is a bad idea, but I gave it a try

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep Mask | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d " " -f1)
Mask=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep Mask | cut -d ':' -f4 | cut -d " " -f1)
IFS=.
IPArray=($IP)
MaskArray=($Mask)
NetArray=()
Start=0
Max=$(( 255 * 255 * 255 * 255 ))
for key in "${!IPArray[@]}";
do
   NetArray[$key]=$(( ${IPArray[$key]} & ${MaskArray[$key]} ))
   Start=$(( $Start + (${NetArray[$key]} << (3-$key)*8) )) 
done
IFS=
echo "Your IP Address   : $IP"
echo "Your N/W Mask     : $Mask"
echo "Your N/W Address  : ${NetArray[@]}"
echo "IPs to be Checked : $(( $Max - $Start ))"
for ((IPs=$Start; IPs <= $Max; IPs++))
do 
   IP=$(( IPs >> 24 ))
   IP="$IP.$(( (IPs >> 16) & 255 ))"
   IP="$IP.$(( (IPs >> 8) & 255 ))"
   IP="$IP.$(( IPs & 255 ))"
   $(ping -c 1 -w 1 $IP >& /dev/null)
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo "$IP exists in Network. Just $(( $Max - $IPs )) more to go."
   fi
done
```

Comment: This will not detect firewalled hosts.

Comment: Yup. Reading about arp-scan :)